# How do I get the correct json structure from serializing an object in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, json, serialization

How to i get the correct json structure from serializing an object in jquery?

my code looks like this:

```
<form id="myform">
<input name="Name[OrganizationName]" id="OrganizationName" />
</form>
```

Which is outputting something like this:

```
"Name[OrganizationName]": "Bill"}
```

but I want this:

```
"Name":{"OrganizationName":"Bill"}
```

here is my serialization js:

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function(){
var o = {};
var a = this.serializeArray();
$.each(a, function() {
    if (o[this.name]) {
        if (!o[this.name].push) {
            o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
        }
        o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
    } else {
        o[this.name] = this.value || '';
    }
});
return o;
};
```

and i'm calling it via:

```
$("#form-add-po").serializeObject();
```

Comment: `name="Name[OrganizationName]"` looks all wrong. Why not `name="OrganizationName"` or `name="OrganizationName[]"` for multiple fields of the same name?

Comment: what's with pasting useless json as subject of post? Very meaningful!

Answer (score 0):

```
$.fn.wrongLogic = function () {
    var o = {};
    this.find('input').each(function () {
        if (this.name.indexOf('[') > -1) {
            var prop = this.name.match(/\[(\w+)\]$/)[1],
                mainProp = this.name.split('[')[0],
                n = {},
            if (o.hasOwnProperty(mainProp)) {
                o[mainProp][prop] = this.value;
            } else {
                n[prop] = this.value;
                o[mainProp] = n;
            }
        } else {
            o[this.name] = this.value;
        }
    })
    return o;
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/h2jE5/1/